# Can Tremorsense be used to fulfill the Blindsense requirement of Blindsight for Eidolons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner

One of the requirements for Blindsight is Blindsense

> Blindsight (Ex): The eidolon's senses sharpen even further, granting it blindsight with a range of 30 feet. The eidolon can maneuver and attack as normal, ignoring darkness, invisibility, and most forms of concealment as long as it has line of effect to the target. Requirements: Summoner level 11th, **blindsense** evolution.

Tremorsense says that it acts like Blindsense if both the Eidolon and the and the creature to be pinpointed are on the ground.

> Tremorsense (Ex): The eidolon becomes attuned to vibrations in the ground, gaining tremorsense with a range of 30 feet. **This works like the blindsense evolution, but only if both the eidolon and the creature to be pinpointed are in contact with the ground.**

Can Tremorsense then be used to get a limited Blindsight that only works if both the Eidolon and the (for example) invisible creature are on the ground?

Per RAW almost certainly not, but since Blindsense is used to pinpoint the creature and Tremorsense does that if it is on the ground(and Tremorsense specifically says it acts like Blindsense if both things are on the ground) would it work?

Does this argument have any validity in the rules or is it just completely up to the DM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It would be a house rule to allow an [eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons)'s [tremorsense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Tremorsense-Ex-) to count as [blindsense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Blindsense-Ex-)

Despite working in a similar fashion, these are different senses with different names and different mechanics. There really isn't any basis in the rules for having one substitute for the other.

But a GM could institute a house rule allowing a player's summoner's [eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons)'s evolution tremorsense to count as blindsense—for acquiring the evolution blindsight, anyway. That player may have to pay for that GM's share of pizza at least once, though.